# extract the number before : and after C in the string (UTC+4:00), (UTC+06:00) in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to use `SUBSTR` and get the values like - +4, +06. from (UTC+4:00), (UTC+06:00) in BigQuery. However, i don't see `FIND` function to know the position of `:` and , position of `+` so that I can directly use:

```
SUBSTR(X,FIND(X,"+"),FIND(X,";")-1)
```

Any alternate solutions to achieve this or do we need to use `REGEXP` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'(\+.*):')` as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'UTC+4:00' x UNION ALL
  SELECT 'UTC+06:00'
)
SELECT x, REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'(\+.*):') 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row x           f0_  
1   UTC+4:00    +4   
2   UTC+06:00   +06
```

Update for more cases:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'UTC+4:00' x UNION ALL
  SELECT 'UTC+06:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'UTC-03:00'
)
SELECT x, IFNULL(REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'UTC(.*):'), '0') 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row x           f0_  
1   UTC+4:00    +4   
2   UTC+06:00   +06  
3   UTC         0    
4   UTC-03:00   -03
```

Comment: Thanks for swift response...i have 2 more scenarios,(UTC) and  
(UTC-04:00)..in first scenario i should get 0 and in the second -4..I am playing around REGEXP but i think iam missing something here..thanks a lot again